# Como fazer o botão ir para links diferentes? Segundo as variáveis do meu "formulário"

Tags: html, button, link

```js
function myFunction() {
  var cor = document.getElementById("Cor").value;
  var tamanho = document.getElementById("Tamanho").value;
  console.log(cor)
  console.log(tamanho)
  if (cor === "Luz Fria" && tamanho === "3m X 2m") {
    document.getElementById("Botao-Compra").href = "https://luzfria.com";
  }
  if (cor === "Luz Quente" && tamanho === "3m X 2m") {
    document.getElementById("Botao-Compra").href = "https://luzquente.com";
  }

}
```

```css
a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Escolha seu kit:</p>

<select id="Cor" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Luz Fria">Luz Fria
    <option value="Luz Quente">Luz Quente

</select>

<select id="Tamanho" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="3m X 2m">3m X 2m


</select>

<a id="Botao-Compra" href="https://luzfria.com">Quero comprar!</a>
```

Bom dia, sou uma pessoa muito leiga no assunto e estou com um problema que não consigo resolver, até postei uma pergunta aqui, mas por não entender muito bem, acabaram desativando a pergunta, então estou tentando novamente, dessa vez me explicando um pouco melhor, antes não deu tempo, porque desativaram.

Preciso que ao clicar no botão **(Quero comprar!)** ele vá para uma URL se o cliente escolher uma cor e para outra URL se o cliente escolher a outra opção de cor, por exemplo, se o cliente selecionar a luz fria, ele vai para http://luzfria.com se o cliente selecionar luz quente, ele vá para http://luzquente.com.

A nossa plataforma de pagamento tem um link para cada combinação na hora de escolher um produto.
Se você escolher o cor "Luz quente" e tamanho "3Mx2M", ao clicar no botão comprar, ele vai pra URL de pagamento da luz quente.
Se você escolher a cor "luz fria" e tamanho 3Mx2M, ao clicar no botão comprar, ele vai para a URL de pagamento da luz fria.
Acontece que ao clicar no botão comprar, ele me leva sempre para o mesmo link, no caso o link inserido no botao-compra: https://luzquente.com

Peço desculpas se não me expliquei direito, sua uma pessoa completamente leiga no assunto, já procurei na internet vários dias, mas não achei.. achei com jQuery, mas não sei inserir isso meu site, ou como funciona.

Comment: Olá Thayná, a outra pergunta não foi desativada, o box azul acima tem a instruções de como resolver, não é permitido duplicar a pergunta para contornar o problema, basta editar a pergunta original e seguir as dicas já mencionadas pelo outro colega: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478311/galera-preciso-que-meu-bot%c3%a3o-v%c3%a1-para-um-link-em-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-das-vari%c3%a1veis-luz-quen#comment896631_478311 - Obrigado pela compreensão.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema na verdade é bem simples, apenas está faltando uma chave para fechar o seu if.

> if (cor === "Luz Quente" && tamanho === "3m X 2m") {

E você deveria deixar como valor padrão o luzfria no botão para que funcione como você desenvolveu.

> Botao-Compra

Não sei que tipo de projeto se destina, se é apenas para estudos, caso não seja, recomendaria você tentar reestruturar melhor sua linha de pensamento.

Comment: A chave na verdade foi apenas uma falha na digitação, já realizei a alteração, agradeço. // 

Mesmo alterando o padrão para luz fria, conforme acima, ao selecionar luz fria ou luz quente, ele me manda sempre para o mesmo link, no caso, o link padrão luz fria no botão.

Comment: Não entendi, o objetivo não seria quando ele modificar o valor do select e clicar no botão ir para o valor selecionado? verifiquei sua modificação e realizei o teste, parece normal pra mim.

Comment: Sim, ir para a URL da luz fria ou luz quente.

Comment: Não está se comportando dessa maneira?

Comment: Não, para mim ele vai sempre para luzfria.com

Comment: Aqui ele funciona, ao colar na html da minha página, para inserir o botão, ele vai sempre pra luz fria, não entendo.

Comment: Criei um chat aqui no stackoverflow, entre lá talvez eu consiga identificar o seu problema, nome: Como fazer o botão ir para links diferentes

Comment: Gustavo, não consegui entrar por não ter pontuação suficiente.
Ao colar exatamente o HTML acima no meu Wordpress, ele reage de maneira distinta, me enviando sempre à URL LUZ FRIA

Comment: Vai ser complicado achar o seu problema apenas nessa parte visto que a mesma está funcionado. Seu problema provavelmente é em alguma outra parte do seu código que está impedindo que os códigos js sejam executados.

Comment: Gustavo Consegue ver no jsdiddle ?  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=BLJaHV4Jur